# Unformatted text coming from php://input

Tags: php, xml, post

I'm trying to pull data from php://input so that I can store the raw data into an XMLElement, so that I can then sort it, and compare the data to a table in one of my databases. I have also tried using $_POST and storing that but the problem that I ran into using $_POST was that I was not getting field headers so I could not store data.

I'm currently using this code to retrieve the raw data from the http POST.

```
$PostContents = file_get_contents(php://input);
echo $PostContents;
```

This is the data that is being returned from that code.

```
xml=%3COPS%3E+%0D%0A%3CAuthentication%3E%3CSecretKey%3Ex44%3C%2FSecretKey%3E+%0D%0A%3C%2FAuthentication%3E+%0D%0A%3CAction%3EUpdate+Person+Status%3C%2FAction%3E+%0D%0A%3CUpdatePersonStatus%3E+%0D%0A%3CPerson%3E+%0D%0A%3CName%3EDavid%3C%2FOrderNumber%3E+%0D%0A%3CAge%3EShipped%3C%2FOrderStatus%3E+%0D%0A%3CAddress%3EThird+Party%3C%2FAddress%3E+%0D%0A%3CPhone%3EUPS+Grd%3C%2FPhone%3E+%0D%0A%3C%2FPerson%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FUpdatePersonStatus%3E+%0D%0A%3C%2FOPS%3E+%0D%0A
```

Here is what is generating that output.

```
<html> 
<body> 
<form action="http://172.16.100.116/php.php" method="post"> 
<textarea name="xml" rows="20" cols="40"><OPS> 
<Authentication><SecretKey>x44</SecretKey> </Authentication> 
<OPS> 
<Authentication><SecretKey>x44</SecretKey> 
</Authentication> 
<Action>Update Person Status</Action> 
<UpdatePersonStatus> 
<Person> 
<Name>David</Name> 
<Age>21</Age> 
<Address>123EasyStreet</Address> 
<Phone>6666666666</Phone> 
</Person>
</UpdatePersonStatus> 
</OPS> 
</textarea> 
<input type=submit> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

(the html file used here is strictly for testing purposes the data that is coming through is within the  plus the header xml information.)

So my question is what do I need to do to get the data from ('php://input') into a XML so I can sort it's information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use urldecode and remove the `xml=`

`urldecode($PostContents);`

This will be the result

```
<OPS> 
<Authentication><SecretKey>x44</SecretKey> 
</Authentication> 
<Action>Update Person Status</Action> 
<UpdatePersonStatus> 
<Person> 
<Name>David</OrderNumber> 
<Age>Shipped</OrderStatus> 
<Address>Third Party</Address> 
<Phone>UPS Grd</Phone> 
</Person>
</UpdatePersonStatus> 
</OPS>
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with urldecode, htmlspecialcharacters, etc. These functions are designed to make life easier :D

Comment: Well I tried using htmlspecialchars() and i didn't get the output that I wanted, however I'm still not getting the output that he listed, I got this instead. `Update Person Status David Shippe
Third Party
UPS Grd` I'm still not getting the <> and </>

Comment: view the source.  You can't see the tags because the browser doesnt show those

Comment: And here I thought that I knew my way around html a little, and I didn't stop to think about that for a second. Thank you, it's nice to know that the data is actually there the way that I want it.

Comment: you'll get the hang of it, and when you do, make sure you help out a noob :D

Comment: I'm looking forward to it :-)